# IntelliJ | Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine | Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ on my windows 10 PC.

I was working my of the maven project, everything was working fine. But i did not understand what i changed in between, getting the following error since then.

[image]

I read a lot in stack-overflow getting many answers stating that change the Java heap size using adding the VM option (-Xms512M -Xmx4096M) into Run/Debug Configurations.

But nothing turnout to be as expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Unrecognized option: -" is a pretty clear problem statement. Your run configuration has options that are invalid. Check your options for a - that does not belong there.

Comment: Make sure you have a 64 bit JDK installed.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html

Don't try to add a value which is to high or not a value.